Example of a conditional probability distribution that is not regular
In Theory of Statistics (Appendix B.3.1) by M. Schervish, the notions of conditional probability and conditional distribution given a sigma-algebra is defined as follows:

Definition B.29 Let $(S, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a probability space. For each $A \in \mathcal{A}$, the conditional probability of $A$ given $\mathcal{C}$ is $\Pr(A|\mathcal{C}) = \mathrm{E}(I_A|\mathcal{C})$. If $\Pr(\cdot|\mathcal{C})(s)$ is a probability on $(S, \mathcal{A})$ for all $s \in S$, then the conditional probabilities given $\mathcal{C}$ are called regular conditional probabilities.


Definition B.30
Let $(S, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a probability space and let $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{B})$ be a measurable space. Suppose that $X: S \to \mathcal{X}$ is a measurable function. Let $P$ be the probability on $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{B})$ induced by $X$ from $\mu$. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-field of $\mathcal{A}$. For each $B \in \mathcal{B}$, let $P(B|\mathcal{C}) = \Pr(A|\mathcal{C})$ where $A = X^{-1}(B)$. We say that any set of functions from $S$ to $[0,1]$ of the form
$$
\lbrace P(B|\mathcal{C})(\cdot),\ \mbox{for all } B \in \mathcal{B} \rbrace
$$
is a version of the conditional distribution of $X$ given $\mathcal{C}$. If the $P(\cdot|\mathcal{C})$ are regular conditional probabilities, then we say that the version of the conditional distribution of $X$ given $\mathcal{C}$ is a regular conditional distribution

Given these definitions, I am interested in a simple example of a conditional probability (distribution) that is not a regular conditional probability (distribution). Somehow, I cannot seem to find any such construction in the usual sources.

The counterexamples will not be trivial. It is a theorem that if $X$ takes values in a Polish space, then then $P[X\in \cdot|\mathcal{C}]$, where $\mathcal{C}$ is a sub $\sigma$ of \mathal{A}$, is a regular conditional probability.
